# MySQL INSERT IGNORE Not working for my 7dtd server script

Tags: mysql, database, insert, duplicates

My table was created using this.

```
CREATE TABLE `Player` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`playername` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`SteamID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`position` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`lastlogin` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`approved` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I am trying to insert new fields into the columns without overwriting the others. The full script downloads a players.xml via FTP then converts a players Steam64ID to the users SteamName then its suppose to insert into the mysql database if the Steam64ID is not already in the database.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("players.xml");
foreach($xml->children() as $player)
{
    $id = $player->attributes()->id;
    $profile = new SteamProfile($id);
    $name = $profile->getUsername();
    $lastlogin = $player->attributes()->lastlogin;
    $position = $player->lpblock->attributes()->pos;
    $sql1= "INSERT IGNORE INTO Player (playername, SteamID, position, lastlogin, approved) VALUES ('$name', '$id', '$position', '$lastlogin', '$approve')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql1,$connection))
    {
            die('Insert Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

It keeps returning this same error with everything I try.

```
Insert Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'm L', '76561198108930923', '', '8/23/2014 7:47:36 PM', '')' at line 1
```

Here is the full code minus the connection information, And yes I know how bad it is that's why I am asking for help. I am 100% new too mysql and php.

```
class SteamProfile
{
    const STEAMAPI_URL_MASK = 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/%s/?xml=1';
    const UNKONWN_NAME_MASK = 'User #%s (Username Not Found)';
    private $steamId;
    private $xml;
    public function __construct($steamId){
        $this->steamId = $steamId;
    }
    public function getUsername(){
        $xml = $this->getXml($this->steamId);
        return $xml->steamID ? (string)$xml->steamID : sprintf(self::UNKONWN_NAME_MASK, $this->steamId);
    }
    private function getXml($steamId){
        if ($this->xml){
            return $this->xml;
        }
        $url = sprintf(self::STEAMAPI_URL_MASK, $steamId);
        if (!$xml = simplexml_load_file($url)){
            throw new UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('Unable to load XML from "%s"', $url));
        }
        return $this->xml = $xml;
    }
}
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) 
{
    echo "Successfully loaded $local_file\n<br />";
} 
else 
{
    echo "There was a problem\n.<br />";
}
ftp_close($conn_id);
$connection = mysql_connect("$hostname","$data_username","$data_password") or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");
$db = mysql_select_db("$db_name", $connection) or die("Couldn't select database.");
$xml = simplexml_load_file("players.xml");
foreach($xml->children() as $player)
{
    $id = $player->attributes()->id;
    $profile = new SteamProfile($id);
    $name = $profile->getUsername();
    $lastlogin = $player->attributes()->lastlogin;
    $position = $player->lpblock->attributes()->pos;
    $sql1= "INSERT IGNORE INTO Player (playername, SteamID, position, lastlogin, approved) VALUES ('$name', '$id', '$position', '$lastlogin', '$approve')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql1,$connection))
    {
            die('Insert Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
sleep(2);
echo "Successfully inserted information to database<br />";
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $steam = $_POST['steam'];
    $approved = $_POST['approved'];
    mysql_query ("UPDATE Player SET approved='$approved' WHERE SteamID = '$steam'");
    if(! $connection )
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo'<br />Updated ('.$steam.') into the database successfully.<br />';
}
else
{
}
$mysql = mysql_query("SELECT playername, SteamID, position, lastlogin, approved FROM Player WHERE position IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(position) <> '' AND approved = ''");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql))
        {
            echo '<br /><table><tr><td>
            Player Name: '.$row['playername'].'<br />
            SteamID: '.$row['SteamID'].'<br />
            Keystone Location: '.$row['position'].'<br />';
            echo 'Admin Approved: ';
            if (isset($row['position']) && ($row['approved'] != "Yes"))
            {
                echo 'No</td></tr></table>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Yes</td></tr></table>';
            }
        }
mysql_close($connection);
?><br />
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF; ?>">
    <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
    <tr><td width="100">Type SteamID</td><td><input name="steam" type="text" id="steam"></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="100">Yes or No</td><td><input name="approved" type="text" id="approved"></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="100"></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="100"></td><td><input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Approve"></td></tr></table></form>
```

Comment: It looks all right. Why don't you echo the whole query, execute in a mySql client and see if there's something that is going wrong (and doesn't seem apparent).

Comment: Im sorry but like I said I am new too mysql and php so I dont quite understand what you mean by execute in a mysql client? Which client?

Answer (score 0):

The player name most likely contains a single quote, and MySQL treats it as a value delimiter.

Run the name through [`mysql-real-escape-string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before inserting into the database:

```
$name = mysql-real-escape-string($profile->getUsername());
```

---

As an aside, note that the `mysql_` methods are deprecated and that you really should be using `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: the $position outputs values like -222,62,1103, And the $name outputs some names like å¾·çŽ›è¥¿äºš and [66ff00]â˜£ Nekhrun â˜£ so I guess it could be the names but when adding `$name = mysql_real_escape_string($profile->getUsername());` it inserts into the database but keeps loading the page none stop and also inserts duplicates. Not to mention somehow messes up my page css.

Comment: Looks like a character encoding issue. No idea what's wrong with the rest of your script.

Comment: Ok did some looking around and it seems there is a $name coming back as I'm L which the single quote is throwing the whole thing. I have tried two things. One is at the top of the script I added the function `public function __toString()
    {
        return sprintf("%s (SteamID: %s)", $this->getUsername(), $this->steamId);
    }` And also used the `$name = mysql_real_escape_string($profile->getUsername());` and now its working ALMOST correctly, Its still inserting duplicates into the database and I need it to only insert  if the $id does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

After getting help from Robby I got the strings right and then I was stuck with getting INSERT IGNORE to not send duplicates, Being half asleep I guess I just forgot to make the column SteamID UNIQUE. So Wiped database and re ran over and over and it seems to all be working find now. Thanks for all the help.